# Windows: Accessing a hidden directory/root directory

Tags: windows, command-line, bash

I have a very basic problem, for which Google Search is not helping me solve :)

I am trying to access a file which was automatically created in the directory

```
~/.ssh/mykey.pub
```

What I would like to do is see the file in either Command Prompt or in my explorer window. However, I cannot figure out how to access the file using the command prompt. I *can* use a 3rd party Terminal to navigate to ~/.ssh (e.g. $ cd ~/.ssh). Also, I believe in OSX this would be incredibly simple, $cd /.ssh or similar. But in the native Windows Command Prompt this sort of thing fails:

```
C:\Users\myname> cd ~
The system cannot find the path specified
```

I've attempted multiple ways of escaping or using \ / to access the ~ directory, to no avail.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

John

Comment: `~` refers to your `HOME` directory in a unix shell. It's location will depend on how your 3rd party Terminal is configured. You need to give us more information about this Terminal program.

Comment: It’d be useful to explain how you created `~/.ssh` in the first place. You’ve tagged your question with Bash but explain that you’re using the native Windows Command Prompt which doesn’t interpret `~` as the HOME directory. You’ll have to use a Unix shell that does.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd, you can use `%userprofile%` for this.

I recommend the usage of powershell, where `~` works fine.